# Remove array element and pass the new one at this position

Tags: solidity

There is a contract where we have artists and anybody can buy an artist, then he becomes the owner of this artist. Also, I have `owners` array and `bulkSend` function that sends ETH to all addresses of the `owners` array.

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.7.0;

contract Cinema {

    struct Artist {
        string name;
        uint price;
        address owner;
    }

    Artist public artist; 
    mapping (uint => Artist) public artists;
    address payable private manager;
    address payable[] public owners;
    uint numArtists;

    constructor() public {
        manager = msg.sender;
    }

    function bulkSend(uint256 amount) public payable {
        uint256 share = amount / owners.length;
        uint256 length = owners.length;
        uint256 currentSum = 0;
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            require(share > 0);
            currentSum += share;
            require(currentSum <= msg.value);
            owners[i].transfer(share);
        }
    }

    function addArtist(string memory name, uint price, address payable owner) public returns(uint artistID) {
        artistID = numArtists++; // artistID is return variable
        artists[artistID] = Artist(name, price, owner);
        owners.push(owner);
    }

    function contribute(uint artistID) public payable {
        Artist storage c = artists[artistID];
        require(msg.value == c.price, "Wrong amount");
        manager.transfer(msg.value / 10); // Send 10% to the manager
        bulkSend(msg.value * 9 / 10); // Send 90% to owners
        c.owner = msg.sender; // Set contributor as owner of the Artist
        delete owners[c.index];
        owners.push(msg.sender); // Add contributor to the owners array
    }
}
```

The question is can I delete an element in the array and somehow past a new element at this position (`.push` doesn't allow to do this)? It's important to keep the order of the elements.

Comment: Please rephrase the words "past a new element", this is not proper English. Do you mean insert the new element at that position? That's not a problem, but it violates the purpose that you have stated further down the same sentence - "important to keep the order of the elements". Your question is thus extremely unclear IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to remove and element at a specific index then add another element to the same index, just simply do this

```
delete owners[i];
```

this will remove the element.

then to add another element at a specific index you can do this.

```
owners[i] = address;
```

make sure to replace address with a real address like the one which has been passed to the function by the user.

Comment: It's working! Looks like I don't need the `delete_element` function at all. Thank you.